# i have added a field in existing module "hr.payslip" from my module.How to show the data of that field

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

an existing module is present i.e hr.payslip,In that module i have added a field from my module . now i want to display the value of that field in hr.payslip module.

models/emailpayslip.py

```
@api.multi #Decorate a record-style method where 'self' is a recordset. The method typically defines an operation on records.
def send_email(self):
    ir_model_data = self.env['ir.model.data']
    payslip_obj = self.env['hr.payslip']
    ids = self.env.context.get('active_ids', [])
    ctx = dict()
    employee_name = ''
    for id_vals in ids:
        payslip_browse = payslip_obj.browse(id_vals)

        global email
        email = payslip_browse.employee_id.work_email

        store_email.sql_example(self,email)#calling method of store_email model

        if payslip_browse.employee_id.work_email:
            template_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('Payslip', 'email_template_payslip')[1]
            ctx.update({
                'default_model': 'hr.payslip',
                'default_res_id': payslip_browse.id,
                'default_use_template': bool(template_id),
                'default_template_id': template_id,
                'default_composition_mode': 'comment',
                'email_to': payslip_browse.employee_id.work_email,
            })
            mail_id = self.env['mail.template'].browse(template_id).with_context(ctx).send_mail(payslip_browse.id, True)
```

## This model is used to create a new table in database and store email to which the payslip is send and date of payslip send

class store_email(models.Model):

```
_name = "store.email"


sendemail = fields.Char(
    string='Send Email',
    default=lambda self: self._get_default_name(),
)
no_of_times = fields.Integer(string='No of Times')    
date_of_email_send = fields.Date(
    string="Date of Email",
    default=lambda self: fields.datetime.now())

@api.model
def _get_default_name(self):
    return "test"


@api.multi
def sql_example(self,temp):
    dob = datetime.today()
    self.env.cr.execute("SELECT * FROM store_email WHERE sendemail = %s",(temp,))
    res = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    if res == []:
        count = 1            
        self.env.cr.execute("INSERT INTO store_email (sendemail,no_of_times,date_of_email_send) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",(temp,count,dob))
        self.env.cr.commit()
    else:
        for x in res:
            count = x[7] + 1

        self.env.cr.execute("UPDATE store_email SET date_of_email_send=%s,no_of_times=%s WHERE sendemail=%s",(dob,count,temp))
        self.env.cr.commit()
```

## Model to add a field in hr.payslip ,Which show last payslip send date

class Add_Field(models.Model):

```
_inherit = "hr.payslip"
last_payslip_send = fields.Date(string='Last Payslip Send')

@api.multi
def last_send_payslip(self):


    self.env.cr.execute("SELECT * FROM store_email WHERE sendemail=%s",(email,))
    res = self.env.cr.fetchall()
```

## my addfile.xml

[add_newfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjCUU.png)

screenshort of the page where i have added the field
[this page cntain the screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA4hh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use compute or default function to load value in to field or you can also pass value while creating record
default function example:

```
name = fields.Char(
string='Name',
default=lambda self: self._get_default_name(),
)

@api.model
def _get_default_name(self):
   return "test"
```

Refer this [link](https://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html) for computed fields

Comment: Hii, plz see the screenshort which i have shared.in that image there is a field Last playslip send,i want to display when i send the playslip by email means the last date of email send

Comment: that Last payslip send field was created by me means from my module

Comment: While sending mail you can pass the current date to your field  write your code inside send email function

Comment: in emailpayslip.py there is a model "Add_Field"  and this model is mainly written to add an extra field to the existing module hr.payslip. and successfully i am added the field to the existing module, Now i want to display the last date of email send in hr.payslip module i.e the page which i have shared the #screenshort of the page this page cntain the screenshort